# Get alert when value in input box is too high

Tags: jquery

When a user puts in a value higher than 1, an alert should appear.

this doesn't work:

```
<input id="inputValue" type="text">
```

```
$(function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#inputValue').keyup(function () {
            if ('#inputValue'.val()) > 1 alert('Value must be a decimal between 0 en 1');

        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Did you try checking your console? (I already know the answer to that)

Comment: You have a syntax error in your code. Look at the error in the Chrome Developer Tools, or load your code in a syntax-checking editor such as Komodo Edit to see the error.

Answer (score 2):

You have lot of errors in code

try this

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
   $('#inputValue').keyup(function () {
        if ($(this).val() > 1 )
            alert('Value must be a decimal between 0 en 1');    
   });
  });
```

Comment: Was about to say the same. +1'd

Answer (score 1):

Your if statement is incorrect.

Try:

```
if ($(this).val()>1){
 alert("....");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your if statement and you missed the $.

```
if ($('#inputValue').val() > 1 ) {
            alert('Value must be a decimal between 0 en 1');

}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/ZPbgG/1/)